# Is there a way to store data in a CSS style declaration or CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to store data in a CSS style declaration? In my tests it's parsing out the custom style names.

For example:

```
<style>
.MyElementData {
   font-family: "Arial";
   firstName: "John";
}
</style>

var css = '.MyElementData { firstName: "John"; font-family: "Arial";}';
var firstStylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = firstStylesheet.cssRules;

// insert rule and get it's value
// returns ".MyElementData { font-family:"Arial" } ";
rules[firstStylesheet.insertRule(css)].cssText;
```

**Background Info:**

I need a way to store basic primative data on my page simply and unobtrusively.

- Using Javascript / JSON seems too cumbersome
- Embedding XML seems like overkill
- Adding tag attributes might work but increases clutter

So since setting my CSS is already part of my workflow it seems like the simplest approach to take. I know it's for styling and layout of the page but it's really a way to store data. The data happens to be about style and layout but to me, there is no reason it can't store other data. In fact the format is nearly identical to JSON.

But now it appears that my custom styles, my name value pairs, are not saved.

If it is completely not possible to store data in CSS then an answer saying that is fine. I will probably use `data-attributeName` on the element tag. I would still like to know if it's possible and if anyone else has figued out how.

Comment: using javascript or json is way less cumbersome than however this is going to work, *if* you can get it to work

Comment: I'm already defining the CSS values on one side and then parsing them out in JavaScript on the other side. For me it's one line of code in each place to transfer the values. But to use JSON or one of the other options I'd have to rewrite part of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure to really understand what you're looking for.
Is it something like that ?

```js
var infoFromCSS = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--preferred_flavor');
alert(infoFromCSS);
```

```css
:root {
  --preferred_flavor: strawberries;
}
```

Comment: Why does `getPropertyValue()` work and not `getComputedStyle(document.body)["--preferred_flavor"]`? Does a double dash hold some significance in making it work?

Comment: yes double dash are for css variables ==> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: @1.21gigawatts more precisely in this case they are *custom properties*